# How to use ajax post a upload file sametime I need to post a string check = 1? `data: fd + '&check=' + 1,`?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

How to use ajax post a upload file sametime I need to post a string check = 1?
`data: fd + '&check=' + 1,` this is not work.  any suggestion?

Thanks.

```
var uf =$('.formname');
var fd = new FormData(formname);    
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
    }
});
```

php

```
if($_FILES && $_POST['check'] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FormData.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData#append%28%29) to add a new set of values

```
var uf =$('.formname');
var fd = new FormData(uf[0]);
fd.append('check','1'); 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's really complicated to pass a file through an ajax postback function. but try this it will help. this question has been asked before. 
[Click and see the answers to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374319/how-can-pass-an-image-location-to-a-php-function-using-jquerys-call-back-functi)

this library will help you achieve all that with alot of ease.

[Mails Up will help. click this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)